# Python exec function how to capture all output (not just explicitly printed output)

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to write an app that can emulate a python console's behavior by executing strings of user code. I am currently executing and capturing output from a users code like so:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

old_stdout = sys.stdout
redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
exec user_code

sys.stdout = old_stdout
#the captured output
print redirected_output.getvalue()
```

This works fine for any statement that is explicitly printed; however, in a real python console if a user were to not explicitly print the value of an expression but instead just type in the expression the value of the expression would print to the console. For instance, if x were a variable equal to 3, typing `x` into the console would result in the console outputting `3`. This behavior, however, does not seem to work by default with exec as typing `exec 'x'` into the console results in no output.

Is there any way to execute code, showing all the output in this manner that a real console does?

Comment: Have you tried `import code; code.interact()`?

Comment: @nneonneo I've checked out the code module, but `interact()` wouldn't suit my purposes as what I am ultimately trying to do is make a program where I can send in a string of code input, run it, and get back the output as a string. InteractiveConsole would definitely handle the input part of that, but I couldn't find a way to get the output from each command anywhere in the code module.

Comment: actually scratch that, I might be able to subclass InteractiveInterpreter and override `write()` to be able to achieve this. I'll try it out and report back.